# Visual Studio 2022 JSON Array Formatting

Tags: json, visual-studio, formatting, visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

With VS 2022 (no extensions), JSON files are being formatted with spaces inside the array braces, i.e.,:

```json
{
  "key": [ "val1","val2","val3" ]
}
```

The preference is to have no spacing between the start/end of the array braces, i.e.,:

```json
{
  "key": ["val1","val2","val3"]
}
```

I've gone through VS editor settings and cannot seem to find anything directly related to the spaces.

I've also tried with an .editorconfig:

```ini
[*.json]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
array_element_spacing = false
```

Any suggestions on how to have VS formatting enforce the rule where there are no spaces after the opening brace and before the closing brace of a json array? Ideally using a .editorconfig setting.

Comment: I don't think its possible.  `array_element_spacing` does not appear to be an [editorconfig property](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties), and according to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022#supported-settings), *"All Visual Studio-supported languages except for XML support EditorConfig editor settings."* - By languages, I think they mean _programming_ languages.  It doesn't seem JSON is supported by this.

Comment: @TimothyG. - I guess I'm not understanding why VS is even trying to format the array? There must be a rule somewhere that VS is following.